# showing hyperlink in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, hyperlink, uilabel

I have a field in sqlite db which has multiple links inside it separted by comma. I displayed one link by placing it in a label and placing an invisible button over it and capturing the click of the button.Is there any other way to show these hyper links as the number of links in the field may change.

Answer (score 1):

Use *UITextView* which automatically detects *phone numbers, http links,* and so on, if its [dataDetectorTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/dataDetectorTypes) property is set properly to a required [UIDataDetectorTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007525-CH3-SW8) value.